# How to prevent the same data being entered into a text file?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

I am trying to create a function that will add the managers name and ID you entered into the text files.

```
{
    File f=new File("Manager.txt");
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f,true))) {
        pw.append(ManID + "," + ManName + "\r\n");
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddCust.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        // TODO add your handling code here:
 {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Manager Added");
        }
    }
```

once typed in, it will imprint the data into the textfile though I still have questions on how to get it to recognise a name that already was inputted and reject it.

how do I make it do so? should encapsulation be applied?

Comment: if ( !currentFile.contains(newText)) currentFile.add(newText); it'll be a bit more complicated, but that's the general idea

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Manager.txt"));
   String line;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Do checking here
   }` try

Answer (score 0):

A simple text file is not the best approach here.

Since you want to search for records which were already added to the list to prevent duplicates, a hashtable would be something to look at.

So, the options you have:
**1.** If the list is not too big and you deifinitely want to store data in a text file, you can load the records into a HashSet(each record can be separated with a line break character, for example) and operate the data in-memory. Once the data has to be written back into the file, just overwrite the whole file with new records.

**2.** Consider using a database engine to store data. You can look at lightweight libraries like [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) or [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).